# overflow:scroll is not showing all of the items in the container

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a container that is holding cards. the container has a   overflow-x: scroll; and is not showing all of the cards(its cutting some of one off). with enough cards it will auto add a scroll bar, yet it seams to be offset by 60px yet there is nothing that might be moving it.

```css
#cardcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.card {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0px 0.5%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```
<div id="cardcontainer">
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
     <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <h3>Content here</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML you're using?

Comment: Yep, I just added it

Comment: `#cardcontainer` is and ID selector. change it to `.cardcontainer`.

Comment: yeah that was a mistake in my addition here, it is id="cardcontainer" in my project.

Comment: Can you edit the snippet I added above and place your compiled CSS in there. We don't know the values for the variables you used.

Comment: I think that I fixed all of the variables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem, try removing the "justify-content" property, it was what messed it up on my case.

If that doesn´t work try with the other positioning properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[the card on the left is being cut off even though i set the overflow to scroll.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH6Hu.png) could u what your declared max-width is and how the result looks like. Thanks ^^

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH6Hu.png

the card on the left is being cut off even though i set the overflow to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

change this: justify-content: center; for this justify-content: safe center; in the #cardcontainer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).